# How to generalize these jquery functions?

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="datum-klassikaal">
<div>01-01-2019 | 02-01-2018</div>
<div>01-02-2019 | 02-02-2018</div>
</div>

<div class="knop-klassikaal">
<div><p><button>Inschrijven</button></p></div>
<div><p><button>Inschrijven</button></p></div>
</div>

<div class="d-klas">
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>

<div class="k-klas">
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>

<input type="text" id="edit-opleidingsdatum" value="">
```

The following code works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".d-klas").append($('.datum-klassikaal').html());
$(".k-klas").append($('.knop-klassikaal').html());

$('.k-klas div:nth-child(1) button').click(function () {
    $('#edit-opleidingsdatum').val($('.d-klas div:nth-child(1)').html())
});

$('.k-klas div:nth-child(2) button').click(function () {
    $('#edit-opleidingsdatum').val($('.d-klas div:nth-child(2)').html())
})

});
```

But this code does not:

```
$(".d-klas").append($('.datum-klassikaal').html());
for (i = 1; i < 24; i++) {
    $('.k-klas div:nth-child(' + i + ') button').click(function () {
        $('#edit-opleidingsdatum').val($('.d-klas div:nth-child(' + i + ')').html())
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong???

BTW, the reason I have to use append() is that Drupal places the content in the wrong place...

Comment: Please provide some sample html as per [mcve]

Comment: I just added all the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons are created on the fly... so by the time they get rendered, the JavaScript is not *aware* of them... instead of:

```
$('.k-klas div:nth-child(' + i + ') button').click(function(){
```

Try:

```
$( document ).on( "click", '.k-klas div:nth-child(' + i + ') button', function() {
```

Comment: Buttons and the stuff that goes into the input values are not created on the fly but placed in different elements by using the append() method. I've tried your solution, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.k-klas div:child button').click(function(){
 $('#edit-opleidingsdatum').val($(this).closest('div').html("")
});
```